# all com.android.libraries support must use same version when including play service in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

I just included ads into my app and as part of that process I included

```
/*google play plugin for adMob*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

as a dependency in my gradle app file. But I'm getting a red underscore error under

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

error says:
all com.android.libraries support must use same version specification. mixing can lead to crashes.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.pctechtips.george.dailyquotes"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        /*firebase */
//        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    })
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*google play plugin for adMob*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Something in that older version of google play services probably uses something from the support library

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/140

Answer (score 0):

play-services-ads:10.2.1 has a dependency onto play-services-basement:10.2.1 which has a dependency onto `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0`.  This is likely the source of the mismatch.

See [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) for more context.